# Full Screen Dual Monitor issue

Tags: xcom-2

The first time I played on full screen it was great. The game took up screen 1 and screen 2 was available for other stuff, I could even mouse over to screen 2. On every other game start Screen 2 is blacked out. Now if I alt-tab in and out of the game a couple times eventually I get screen 2 back. Does anyone know a better, consistent, solution?

I tried borderless window but that just goes to the upper left hand of the screen and does not fill the entire screen.

Comment: any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Did you try setting the resolution after setting it to borderless windowed?

Comment: The option is disabled.